# Creating Reports in ASP.Net with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, reporting-services

We are looking to add Microsoft Reports - SSRS to one of our internal websites.

The database has all the reporting features installed.

The website is using Entity Framework 4 for all data.

I have been able to create a report using the old fashioned way of creating a DataSet (*.XSD) and this works well.

My question though, is it possible to utilise the existing Entity Framework in the site for the data required by the reports? Rather than having to re-invent the wheel and make a whole DataSet, along with relationships etc..

It's a website and not application, so this (http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx) doesn't seem to apply; I don't see the DataSource (in part 2 of the tutorial)

**Update**

As a side-note, we would like to steer clear of expensive third-party controls etc.

Also, another way to look at the issue might be to generate the *.XSD from the entity framework entity model; is this possible? It's not ideal though would get us up and running..

Answer (score 9):

Below is a quick sample of how i set the report datasource in one of my .NET winForms applications.

```
public  void getMyReportData()
    {
        using (myEntityDataModel v = new myEntityDataModel())
        {

            var reportQuery = (from r in v.myTable
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       l.ID,
                                       l.LeaveApplicationDate,
                                       l.EmployeeNumber,
                                       l.EmployeeName,
                                       l.StartDate,
                                       l.EndDate,
                                       l.Supervisor,
                                       l.Department,
                                       l.Col1,
                                       l.Col2,
                                       .......,
                                       .......,
                                       l.Address
                                   }).ToList();


            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("nameOfReportDataset", reportQuery);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

            Stream rpt = loadEmbededReportDefinition("Report1.rdlc");
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(rpt);
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            //Another way of setting the reportViewer report source

            string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            string reportPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"rdlcReports\Report1.rdlc");
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;

            reportParameter p = new ReportParameter("DeptID", deptID.ToString());
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new[] { p });

        }
    }




    public static Stream loadEmbededReportDefinition(string reportName)
        {
            Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Stream _reportStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectNamespace.rdlcReportsFolder." + reportName);

            return _reportStream;
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

My approach has always been to use RDLC files with object data sources and run them in 'local' mode.  These data sources are ... my entities!  This way, I'm using all of the same business logic, string formatting, culture awareness, etc. that I use for my web apps.  There are a some quirks, but I've been able to live with them:

- RDLC files don't like to live in web projects.  We create a separate dummy winform project and add the RDLC files there.
- I don't show reports in a viewer.  I let the user download a PDF, Word, or Excel file and choose to save or open in the native viewer.  This saves a bunch of headaches, but can put some folks off, depending on requirements.  For mobile devices, it's pretty nice.
- Since you are not using SSRS, you don't get the nice subscription feature.  You are going to build that, if required.  In many ways, though, I prefer this.

However, the benefits are really nice:

- I'm using all of the same business logic goodness that I've already written for my views.
- I have a custom ReportActionResult and DownloadReport controller method that allows me to essentially run any report via a single URL.  This can be VERY handy.  It sure makes a custom subscription component easier.
- Report development seems to go pretty quick, now that I only need to adjust entity partial classes to tweak a little something here or there.  Also - If I need to shape the data just a bit differently, I have LINQ.

Comment: how do you setup a object data sources for VS 2013

Comment: This answer is a long comment, but answer.

Answer (score 2):

We too use SSRS as "local" reports.  We create Views in SQL server, then create that Object in our application along with the other EF Domain Models, and query that object using our DbContext.  We use an ASPX page and use the code behind (Page_Load) to get the data passed to the report.

Here is an example of how we query it in the Page_Load Event:

```
        var person = MyDbContext
            .Query<ReportModel>()
            .Where(x => x.PersonId == personId)
            .Where(x => x.Year == year)
            .Select(x =>
            {
                PersonId = x.PersonId,
                Year = x.Year,
                Name = x.Name
            });

        var datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", person.ToList());

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            myReport.Visible = true;
            myReport.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            myReport.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Areas\Person\Reports\PersonReport.rdlc";
        }

        myReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        myReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        myReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create a report (.rdlc) with a blank data source connection string, a blank query block and a blank DataSetInfo (I had to modify the xml manually). They must exist in file and be blank as follows:

```
SomeReport.rdlc (viewing as xml)
...
<DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="conx">
    <ConnectionProperties>
    <DataProvider />
    <ConnectString />
    </ConnectionProperties>
    <rd:DataSourceID>19f59849-cdff-4f18-8611-3c2d78c44269</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
</DataSources>
...
<Query>
    <DataSourceName>conx</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText />
    <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
</Query>
<rd:DataSetInfo>
    <rd:DataSetName>SomeDataSetName</rd:DataSetName>
</rd:DataSetInfo>
```

now in a page event, I use a SelectedIndexChanged on a DropDownList, bind the report datasource as follows:

```
protected void theDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (theDropDownList.SelectedIndex == 0)
        return;

    var ds = DataTranslator.GetRosterReport(Int64.Parse(theDropDownList.SelectedValue));
    _rvReport.LocalReport.ReportPath = "SomePathToThe\\Report.rdlc";
    _rvReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SomeDataSetName", ds));
    _rvReport.Visible = true;
    _rvReport.LocalReport.Refresh();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've a lot of troubles because cant select an object as datasource

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WCF-Service as Datasource and so re-use your application data and logic for your report. This requires a SQL-server standard edition at least i believe. So no can do with the free SQL-express edition.

Comment: Tried this approach too, though it seems that this will only work if it's a web application and not web site because the reference isn't available in the report designer (the wizard where you select your datasource) - the reference doesn't exist.

Comment: it's the only way to access your code in your reports. If you can't setup a web-app for your WCF service you can best access your data with plain sql or a stored procedure

Comment: yah, starting to see that. We built stored procedures for the reports around the same time as asking this question; just really don't like having the data access logic in different places...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LINQ** with **RDLC Report** which is quite easy to use

```
LinqNewDataContext db = new LinqNewDataContext();
var query = from c in db.tbl_Temperatures
                    where c.Device_Id == "Tlog1"
                    select c;
var datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", query.ToList());
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Report6.rdlc";    
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```