# Using Entity Framework 6 as a data adapter for Jasper Reports

Tags: c#, entity-framework, jasper-reports, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 in a MVC.Net project. I want to be able to re-use the Entity Framework logic to produce Jasper reports, without having to re-implement all of the SQL queries by hand and maintain duplicated logic. There appears to be no out of the box way to use Entity Framework as a data adapter in Jasper.

A similar question for Reporting Services is [Creating Reports in ASP.Net with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146425/creating-reports-in-asp-net-with-entity-framework)

Is there a way to use Entity Framework as a data adapter with a Jasper report?

Using EF6, PostgreSQL, MVC.Net, Jasper Reports (with Jasperstarter).

Comment: In java you can pass directly the objects using a [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html), however in your case running with Jasperstarter either use an xml or directly a query with parameters passed from application (which probably is quicker then generating xml), what is best well that's probably primary opinion based.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I have edited the question

Comment: Ok will vote to reopen, but I do not think there is, it's a java lib, just scrap c# and you are home free :)